# Как сделать так, чтобы окно opener закрывалось на любом сайте?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой букмарклет

```
javascript:hrf = 'https://vk.com';
features = 'width=540,height=300,left=' + parseInt(screenX + ((outerWidth - 540) / 2), 10) + ',top=' + parseInt(screenY + ((outerHeight - 300) / 2), 10);
newWindow = window.open("","_blank",features);
newWindow.document.write("<script>alert('!!!')</script><h1><a id='idid' href = 'javascript:alert(window.opener.window.location)'>i</a></br><a href = 'javascript:alert(window.opener.window.close(true))'>x</a></h1>");
newWindow.focus();
```

и при нажатии на `x` в попап окне одни сайты успешно закрываются, а вот другие - нет. Например, гугл и вк не хотят закрываться, а, к примеру, википедия успешно закрывается.

Там в коде букмаркета есть кое-что лишнее - вы не пугайтесь, я на него стараюсь не дышать. джаваскрипт же молчит об ошибках если что-то не так. в таком виде он хоть через раз, но работает, а нужно, чтобы в 100% случаев срабатывал.

Поясню: должно закрываться то окно, из которого я запускаю букмарклет.

Дело в том, что код этого букмарклета ляжет в основу новой системы навигации для браузера, но вот пока он сыроват.

Букмарклет будет висеть на "домике" (home) и вызываться по клику на "домике" или по <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd>.

Comment: что именно вы хотите закрыть при нажатии `x`?

Comment: должно закрываться окно из которого был запущен букмарклет

Comment: в общем случае - это невозможно

Comment: [вот тут подробнее](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)